# How to implement dynamic GUI in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, rendering, custom-tag

i have a requirement where i need to display some fields on the JSP. These fields are dynamic in nature, meaning, for ex:, if i changed some value in the dropdown, some fields will be hidden and some other fields might come. I dont want to write Javascripts for show/hide of divs, rather want logic to be coded somewhere at server side.

I have an idea of implementing a custom tag library, but i wnat if i could get an out of the box solution.

any new suggestions or solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You had better do it in JavaScript. Having said that, you can send AJAX request to get the new form fields based on the input provided. For example, have a `<div>` to set the HTML coming from the server.

Comment: I suggest to use any of available JS libraries to make it extra easy like http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use struts framework , there are some tags which can hide and show fields based on values

[Logic/logicout tags example](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-logic-tag-example-1.html)

Comment: I'd not recommend using Struts 1 anymore. For new projects you should definitely switch to Struts 2.

Comment: @Thomas : based on requirment we can shift to struts1 or 2 , still some projects are building on struts 1

Comment: If existing projects use struts 1, then you don't have to switch, but please don't suggest to use struts 1 for new projects (the OP didn't mention it but I assume he's not using struts right now).

Comment: @Thomas : He didnot mention it, may be he want to use some mvc framework

Comment: As I said, if he wants to use a __new__ (meaning new for him, not currently using) framework, then please suggest a current one (like struts 2 and not struts 1).

Comment: I am not using any framework as of now. I was thhinking of Struts 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a web framework, try [Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/). It provides tags like `<s:if test="some ognl expression" ...>` to selectively render html content.

Otherwise you could just go with the [JSTL core](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) tags, which provide a `<c:if text="some Java EL expression" ...>` and a `<c:choose ...>` tag ( [Example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/if.html) ).

Remember to reload the page after changing select box values in order to update the UI.
For this some JavaScript might be needed.

Comment: I am not favouring <c:if/> tags as they will clutter the JSP. I want the tag should be intelligent enough to render or not to render the body.

Comment: @Ashish Well, the tags would still have to have a body in the jsp in order to render it. Alternatively you could have tags that render their body themselves (i.e. a combobox that checks itself whether it is visible or not), however, that would require special JSP components. In that case you might want to have a look at JSF(-like) frameworks (JSF 2.0 doesn't support JSP anymore), which provide tags with a `rendered` attribute taking an expression.

Comment: @Ashish - Please also update your question and mention you want those "self-checking"/intelligent tags, so that others are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

DOM (Document Object Model) in Javascript is very powerful and cross browser.

to remove a node on UI

1.removeChild(nodename)

to add a node on UI

2.elementNode.insertBefore(new_node,existing_node)

I used it. it works well.
more information on DOM.

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp